# MulterError: Unexpected field , reactjs, vuejs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, multer

route.js

```
const parser = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/api/images', parser.single("MyImage"), function(req, res){
  console.log(req) // to see what is returned to you
  const image = {};
  image.url = req.file.url;
  image.id = req.file.public_id;
  res.send({data:image}) 
});
```

imageUpload.js or imageUpload.vue or  imageUpload.vue.jsx

```
uploadImage = (event) => {

   let data = new FormData();
   data.append("name", "orderImage");

   data.append("file", event.target.files[0]);

   let config = {
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "image/png"
    }
  };

  axios.post('api/images', data, config).then(response => {
    console.log("image upload response > ", response);
  });
 }
```

getting an error whenever i tried to upload the image to cloudinary cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

change route.js

```
 const multerName = 'MyImage'
 app.post('/api/images', parser.single(multerName), function(req, res){
```

mageUpload.js or imageUpload.vue or imageUpload.vue.jsx

```
const multerName = 'MyImage'
data.append("name", "orderImage");
```

here also same  multerName as route.js

```
data.append("multerName", event.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: You just answered to your question 2 mins after posting it?

Answer (score 0):

change route.js

```
 const multerName = 'MyImage'

 app.post('/api/images', 
    parser.single('anotherFile'), //here exact change
       function(req, res){
```

after change

```
app.post('/api/images', parser.single('anotherFile'), function(req, res){
```

mageUpload.js or imageUpload.vue or imageUpload.vue.jsx

```
const multerName = 'MyImage'
data.append("name", "orderImage");
```

here also same  multerName as route.js

```
data.append("file",  //here exact change
   event.target.files[0]);
```

After change

```
 data.append("multerName", event.target.files[0]);
```

need to maintain same names in both frontend and backend formData()